# Does tick affect mob movement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to create a floating tripwire hook trap that if anything fall on it , it will trigger the piston to close the water so anything that fall to it die by fall damage , i have read https://minecraft.wiki/w/Transportation and know that fall speed does increase each tick , but the server i am playing on have very low tps (9-13 tps average) so im afraid the piston will turned on too late due to tps , so does my tripwire hook trap still work perfectly even with unstable tick  speed?

Answer (score 1):

Redstone will operate at exactly the same speed as it is bsed on gametick speed (2 gameticks = 1 redstone tick)

Comment: This is assuming a vanilla server. If the server is running on Spigot, Paper, etc, not vanilla, then it's very likely the trap will fail - under heavy load these servers often defer piston movement "for later".